# Gaussian Poincare Inequality for multivariate functions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, normal-distribution

The Gaussian Poincare inequality states that for a differentiable function $f: \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $d$-dimensional Gaussian $X \sim N(0,\Sigma)$, then
$$
\text{Var}(f(X)) \le \mathbb{E} \langle \Sigma \nabla f(X), \nabla f(X) \rangle.
$$
I would like to know if there is an extension to multivariate functions: For $g:\mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}^k$, can we say something about $\text{Var}(g(X)) \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times k}$ along the same lines of the poincare inequality? Can we say something about $\|\text{Var}(g(X))\|_{\text{op}}$?

Comment: It seems that a similar question has just been asked here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4697157/how-to-generalize-the-gaussian-poincare-inequality-for-vector-valued-random-vari/4697177#4697177 You may find the answer helpful

Answer (score 0):

Yes. it is highly related to the random matrix theory and the Multivariate normal approximation problem (e.g. multivariate stein's method).

You may find [the following paper by Tropp](http://users.cms.caltech.edu/%7Ejtropp/papers/HT20-Poincare-Inequalities.pdf) be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

@WeakLearner, did you get a satisfactory answer from this post? I looked through the Tropp papers recommended by Woo Jong (i.e., https://arxiv.org/pdf/2006.16562.pdf and [http://users.cms.caltech.edu/~jtropp/papers/HT20-Poincare-Inequalities.pdf](http://users.cms.caltech.edu/%7Ejtropp/papers/HT20-Poincare-Inequalities.pdf)). However, these are concerned with maps $f: \Omega \to \mathbb{H}_d$ where $\mathbb{H}_d$ is real linear space of $d \times d$ self-adjoint complex matrices. I don't see how this applies to maps $f: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^k$,  here $\Omega$ is a Polish space, so we can take $\Omega$ to be $\mathbb{R}^d$. Am I missing something?

Comment: unfortunately, no i didn't - the paper mentioned doesn't solve the issue at all for the reasons you mention